# auf jeden/keinen Fall

Tags: word-usage, etymology

Weiß jemand woher das **auf** in *"auf keinen / jeden Fall"* kommt und weshalb es nicht (mehr) *"**in** jedem / keinem Fall"* heißt?

Für mich hört sich mindestens die Variante *in jedem Fall* sehr "natürlich" an, aber [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%22in%20jedem%20Fall%22%2C%22auf%20jeden%20Fall%22%2C%22in%20keinem%20Fall%22%2C%20%22auf%20keinen%20Fall%22&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&case_insensitive=on&corpus=31&smoothing=0&direct_url=t4%3B%2C%22%20in%20jedem%20Fall%20%22%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3B%22%20in%20jedem%20Fall%20%22%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%22%20In%20jedem%20Fall%20%22%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2C%22%20auf%20jeden%20Fall%20%22%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3B%22%20auf%20jeden%20Fall%20%22%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%22%20Auf%20jeden%20Fall%20%22%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2C%22%20in%20keinem%20Fall%20%22%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3B%22%20in%20keinem%20Fall%20%22%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%22%20In%20keinem%20Fall%20%22%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2C%22%20auf%20keinen%20Fall%20%22%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3B%22%20Auf%20keinen%20Fall%20%22%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%22%20auf%20keinen%20Fall%20%22%3B%2Cc0#t4%3B%2C%22%20in%20jedem%20Fall%20%22%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3B%22%20in%20jedem%20Fall%20%22%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%22%20In%20jedem%20Fall%20%22%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2C%22%20auf%20jeden%20Fall%20%22%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3B%22%20auf%20jeden%20Fall%20%22%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%22%20Auf%20jeden%20Fall%20%22%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2C%22%20in%20keinem%20Fall%20%22%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3B%22%20in%20keinem%20Fall%20%22%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%22%20In%20keinem%20Fall%20%22%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2C%22%20auf%20keinen%20Fall%20%22%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3B%22%20Auf%20keinen%20Fall%20%22%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%22%20auf%20keinen%20Fall%20%22%3B%2Cc0) gibt mir eher den Hinweis, dass es sich nicht um eine Entwicklung handelt. Könnte es eine Übernahme aus dem Englischen ("in any case") ähnlich zu *"Sinn machen"* sein?

Bei der Formulierung *"auf alle Fälle"* existiert ja ebenfalls ein "Gegenstück" mit *"in allen Fällen"*, woher kommt also das *auf*?

Comment: Woher nimmst du die Behauptung, es würde nicht (mehr) *in jedem/keinen Fall* heißen? Kann ich leider nicht nachvollziehen

Answer (score 4):

"Auf jeden Fall" bedeutet unbedingt, ganz bestimmt, sicher, unter allen Umständen. "Auf keinen Fall" das Gegenteil, also niemals, unter keinen Umständen, etc. Sicherheit wird angenommen, eine Option ist ausgeschlossen.

"In jedem Fall" bedeutet jeweils für sich, in jedem Einzelfall, von Fall zu Fall und kann beispielsweise spezifische Besonderheiten oder Optionen der Einzalfälle ausdrücken.

Zwischen den beiden Wendungen mit Tendenzen in die eine oder andere Richtung würde ich "jedenfalls" sehen.

Siehe auch Duden "[Fall](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Fall_stuerzen_hinfallen_Sache)", Bedeutung 2a.

DWDS "[Fall](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Fall#2)" hat "in jedem Fall" nicht, sondern führt "in" nur in Verbindung mit optionalen Unterscheidungen.

Die "auf" Präposition mit Akkusativ sehe ich hier schlicht als Bedeutung einer zeitlichen oder kausalen Folge an, nach [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/auf_Praeposition), Absatz 2c. "Auf" in Verbindung mit Dativ würde ja eher ein räumliches Übereinander bedeuten.

Comment: Das hattoch mit Etymologie nichts zu tun. Eine Dudel-Definition beinhaltet natürlich schon die gesuchte Bedeutung. Es macht deshalb prinzipiel keinen Sinn darauf zu verweisen ohne die Ausschlag gebende Stelle zu zitieren. Zuberwarten steht, da steht nix. Auch sonst kommt hier zu usage nicht viel. Die ersten paragraphen behandeln allenfalls Meaning

Comment: Hmhm. Zu lange im Zuber dudeln kann Auschlag geben :-)

Answer (score 1):

> Für mich hört sich mindestens die Variante *in jedem Fall* sehr "natürlich" an

Für mich nicht. Ich finde es schwierig herauszustellen in welchen Fällen ich *auf jeden* bevorzugen würde. Man kann die zwei ja nur schwer verwechseln.

Es käme auf die Herkunft der Phrasen insgesamt an. Ich behaupte mal, da sei vom Fragesteller Vorarbeit zu leisten, ggf. durch stellen der richtigen Frage. Eine steile Hypothese könnte ggf. ein wesentlich älteres Datum anzeigen, als schriftliche Beweise zuließen. Eine klassische Zwickmühle aus nicht wollen und nicht können ergibt sich. So geht hier nichts. Problematisch ist unter anderem, dass *Fall* neben gleichbedeutend *Casus* (vgl. Lat. *cado* "ich falle*, sowie Engl. *case* "(kriminal-)Fall" usw.) wie eine Lehnübersetzung anmutet, sowie Fall überhaupt verschiedenste Bedeutungen abdeckt.

Ich erwarte, dass *auf jeden Fall* aus *jedenfalls* herruehrt und dies widerum mit *allenfalls*, sowie *Vielfalt*, *mulitply*, etc. aus Morphosyntax heraus zu begründen sei. Entscheidend dürfte die Entwicklung zu *je-* sein. Dies soll mit *ewig* wurzelverwandt sein (DWDS.de, Wiktionary).

*Hypothese*: Demnach könnte man ansetzen *?ewj'()fall*, quasi, wobei offen bleibt woher der Nasal stammt, etwa aus Beugung wegen Umdeutung zur Nominalphrase, folgt daraus. Zu beweisen wüsste ich das aber nicht. Woher auch, wenn Deutsch die möglicher Weise einzige Sprache ist, die es in der Form erhalten haben mag. Dabei steht English *anyway* recht nahe, auch *always*. Insbesondere *e-ver* soll tatsächlich im Anlaut verwandt sein, das Ende ist aber noch nicht abzusehen (Wiktionary). Allerdings bieten sich janz sicher fiele andere Möglichkeiten.

Merke, Etymologie ist kein Popularitätswettbewerb in der Disziplin Freistil auf 100 Meter Abschreiben. Ich wiederhole, ist es nicht! Demnach kann ich Frank und Frei bis zum Beweis des Gegentei behaupten, die richtige Antwort weiß der Geier.

### Das ist dann ja auch eine Antwort, "unbekannt", wenn nicht klar ist, ob es mit er Richtung "auf" oder dem Nomen *Fall* ursprünglich doch nichts gemein hät.

Nicht zuletzt bleibt anzumerken, wie schon <strike>im Eingang</strike> eingangs angedeutet, dass es sich jedenfalls um eine Kontraktion handelt, zuweilen auch als Univerbation *f'jeden*. Dies wird meist adverbial oder alleinstehend als Interjektion verwendet und wirkt schlicht bestätigend wie *Jawohl, ja!* usw. Das zeigt sich unter anderem daran, dass die Univerbation wenngleich selten als Adverb genutzt wird. *Der hat auf jeden voll verrissen*, o.ä., citation needed. Vgl. dazu *Der hat* ja *ne Vollmeise*, bzw. *der hat ja/gar/ja gar keine Ahnung* (s. dazu Niederdeutsche Lautverschiebungen, wie auch Nordsee-spezifisches, also Friesisch *i-epen* "open", d. h. *geöffnet, offen*).

---

Nachträglich noch eine weitere Überlegung. Wenngleich ich unser *auf-jeden* aus *aiwo- herleiten und damit subtil unterstellen wollte, die Formen mit in seien eben zufällige Neuerungen, könnte man doch versuchen *nie-* zu vergleichen, sowie auch *un-* und *ne* (*nicht*, auch als Fragepartikel) zusammengehören, obwohl man dann erst einmal *unfall* erwarten würde. Allah dingens wäre **ney- (citation needed), bzw. ist *nie* "never" durchaus erklärbar als Negation von *heyu-, je* (Althochdeutsch *io* und *nio*). Der Vokal im Anlaut bleibt fraglich, siehe aber auch Französisch *en, en case de* "im Fall dass", oder Niederländisch *en* "not" (neben anderen Bedeutungen), bzw. umgekehrt Vulgär-Latein *in-* "un-". Hinzu kommt dass unser *irgend-* wohl mit Skandinavisch *ingen* ("nicht") ein Verhältnis führte, um nicht zu sagen auch verwandt gewesen sein mag (Wiktionary). Ich bezweifle, ob sich heute noch nach nachweisen ließe, dass unsere beiden Varianten komplementär mit entgegengesetzter Polarität verwendet wurden, vgl. aber *in keinem Fall*.

Leider jottes han ich eingangs ausgeschlossen, irgenwelche Präferenz für Verwendung nahelegen zu wollen. Nun werd ich nicht behaupten, *in keinem Fall* vor *auf keinem Fall* zu Nutz ziehen. Das wäre mehr an den Haaren herbeigezogen als die Frau eines Keule schwingenden Urindogermanen. Ich meine aber doch, das Adverb *jedenfalls* gehöre viel eher der Hochsprache an, denn dessen Verwendung in der Kanzleisprache klingt für meine Begriffe jedenfalls archaisch.

Answer (score 0):

Ein kleines Beispiel zur Verständnis:

Ich habe drei Eimer.
Ich gebe *auf* alle Eimer(Fälle) Wasser.
Ich gebe *in* alle Eimer(Fälle) Wasser.

Es wird absolut beides verwendet, und umgangssprachlich wird vielleicht auch nicht so sehr darauf geachtet, korrekt ist beides und sollte mit dem Englischem eher wenig am Hut haben.